# Converting Strings of formatted text, Is there a better way to do this?

Tags: java

Here is the text file that I am parsing

> //(*
>       **Set Table Limits Min + color code** *
>       1,3
>       2,3
>       5,0
>       10,5
>       15,6
>       25,8
>       50,7
>       100,10
>       * Set Table Limits Max*
>       100
>       200
>       300
>       500
>       1000
>       2000
>       3000
>       5000
>       10000
>       <>

and here is code

```
private void addMinBets(String aDataRow) {

    // Process Min limits
    // Does aDataRow start with "!= *"
    // process string
    // else do nothing
    // Process Max limits
   if (!aDataRow.contains("*")){
            // Find the index of ","
             // Get string before ","
             // Get string After ","
       if (aDataRow.contains(",")){
                 // Add Max bet to maxArraylist
           String parts[] = aDataRow.    split("\\,");
           Log.d("Split"," Match must be min =  $" + parts[0]);
           Log.d("Split"," Match must be min color = " + parts[1]);
       }
       if (!aDataRow.contains("*")){

           if (!aDataRow.contains(",")){

               if (!aDataRow.contains("<")){

                 Log.d("Split"," Match must be max bet = $ " + aDataRow);

               }


           }

       }

   }
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this in code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you tried using regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you only want to log strings that are of the form:

1. digit(s)
2. digit(s),digit(s)

Then you want to use regex like @Thusitha Thilina Dayaratne suggested.

Made a quick sample using [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) as example.

```
private void addMinBetsV2(String aDataRow) {
    //[one or more digits]
    String numRegex = "(\\d)+"; 
    //[one or more digits],[one or more digits]
    String commaNumRegex = numRegex + "," + numRegex;

    if (aDataRow.matches(numRegex)) {
        Log.d("Split"," Match must be max bet = $ " + aDataRow);
    } else if (aDataRow.matches(commaNumRegex)) {
        String parts[] = aDataRow.    split("\\,");
        Log.d("Split"," Match must be min =  $" + parts[0]);
        Log.d("Split"," Match must be min color = " + parts[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works great and expandable without the overhead.. need to get better grasp on formatting expressions.